# how to goto a page by code?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I tried using `window.location="#pageLogin"`.
It works in my desktop but appears a blank in my android device.

After doing some search,I uses `$.mobile.changePage` like this

```
var user;
$(document).ready(function(){
    user=GetCurrUser();
    if(user==null){
            $.mobile.changePage("#pageLogin", {
            transition: "pop",
            reverse: false,
            changeHash: false
        }); 
    }
});
```

Still nothing appears,even on desktop (Chrome).

Is there any better way to do that?

**UPDATE**
The error message in firebug of `$.mobile.changePage` is 
`settings.pageContainer is undefined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is at `$(document).ready(function(){});`.It seems that the jQuery mobile framework had not loaded at this stage.I have to use `$("#pageMain").live("pagecreate", function() {});` instead.

Answer (score 3):

The jQuery Mobile way works for me, here's the example of code:

```
$.mobile.changePage($("#dashboard"), "none");
```

Not sure what could be your error. Can you try to reproduce it in jsFiddle?

Answer (score 0):

`window.location.href = "#pageLogin";` ?

Comment: you mean `window.location.hash`.  That code will just try to send you to that alone stripping the url of it's relative path

Answer (score 0):

```
location.replace(window.location.protocol + "//" + location.host + location.pathname + "#pageLogin")
```

Maybe that?